# OpenERP Ir attachment store

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP version 7.0 I define ir_attachment.location in system parameter and than my attachment is store in given folder.

All works are fine, But any setting available so I can store my attachment in to cloud or web space? Suppose I want to store my attachment in google drive.

Comment: That is not really a programming question. Anyway, you may mount your cloud space as virtual filesystem, so openERP does'nt know anything where the files go. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting in OpenERP to handle that besides setting the on-disk location.  However, in *nix at least (not sure about Windows) you can pretty much mount a file system anywhere, so simply mount your cloud in the appropriate spot and you're good to go.